# Error: No matching function for call to when using GeoDataPlacemark::setStyle

Tags: qt5, marble

I am using marble with qt5 and I am getting this error message when executing these lines of code. Any Idea?(Can it be that I am missing any packages?)
Thanks!

```
styleArch = new Marble::GeoDataStyle;
        styleArch->setIconStyle( *icon );
        place->setStyle( styleArch );
```

[image: Image of Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API changed from pointers to shared pointers. This should work:

```
styleArch = new Marble::GeoDataStyle;
styleArch->setIconStyle( *icon );
place->setStyle( Marble::GeoDataStyle::Ptr( styleArch ) );
```